# How to download zip file to iphone?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to download a zip file. It returns 0 bytes for myURL1, this code works for a xml file which returns roughly 200000 bytes.

```
NSURL *myURL1 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.enginbodur.com/files/GetAccounts.zip"];
NSURL *myURL2 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.jjfoodservice.com/rss/productscatalogue.xml"];

NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:myURL];
```

Can someone show me how to download zip files from a url?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, but is inadvisable. Your code will block while the file downloads, very bad practice. Learn how to use `NSURLConnection` instead.

Comment: This is not working btw. I will check NSURLConnection anyway. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

NSURLConnection would indeed be a better solution. 
also, might sound silly, have you tried it with the url all lowercase?